# Looking for a Midrash / Commentary about David Hamelekh condemning the notion of Theater (Play-pretend / Acting etc.)

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, king-david

By any chance, does anyone remember something along these lines? I heard it back in my Yeshiva days and it always puzzled me (what did David Hamelekh mean by it more precisely? What danger did he foresaw in these kind of medium?)

So maybe knowing the precise source I'd be able to find out more... Really hope it's not one of these deformed or inflated "I heard / I read" chatter G.od forbid lol

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to Rabbi Shim'on ben Pazi's exposition of [T'hillim 1:1](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2601.htm) (['Avoda Zara 18b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.18b?lang=bi)): "דרש ר' שמעון בן פזי אשרי האיש אשר לא הלך לטרטיאות ולקרקסיאות של עובדי כוכבים".

Comment: More likely it was the episode when they said "hey, let's pretend-play war!" And it leads to a real one.

Comment: @Shalom Possibly ([II Shmuel 2:14](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.2.12), "ויאמר אבנר אל יואב יקומו נא הנערים וישחקו לפנינו ויאמר יואב יקמו"). One might connect your source with an interpretation of T'hillim 1:1 similar to that of R' Shimon ben Pazi to suggest a novel (?) idea that David began T'hillim with the same theme that disturbed him to his dying day (I M'lachim 2:5-6), lamenting on the counsel of the wicked that resulted in fatal "playacting", the death of Asael, and ultimately the death of Avner and the curse of Yoav (which also fell on David's own descendants - Sanhedrin 48b).

Comment: @Fred bravo! Wow! Thank you.

Comment: @Fred I’m not quite following you: could you please remind me the context (and thus I miight be able to grasp what you mean by linking tye beginning of his complaint to the end of his life on earth… Hopefully, as I’m still a beginner here lol). Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Zacchino See 2 Shmuel chapters 2-3, and [1 M'lachim 2:5-6](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a02.htm#5). Avner and Yoav commanded rival armies (Avner commanded the army of Ishboshes, and Yoav commanded David's army). They both arrived with squads of troops at a pool at the same time, and they agreed to have their troops compete in duels. Most commentaries understand that the original intention was merely for sport, not meant to involve lethal combat. Nevertheless, lethal combat ensued, resulting in a cascade of tragedies. On his deathbed, David commanded Shlomo to punish Yoav for his actions.

Comment: @Zacchino David began the first verse in all of sefer Tehillim by saying, "Happy is the man who does not walk in the counsel of the wicked". In *Avoda Zara* (18b), R' Shimon b. Pazi, applying this advice to his Roman-era milieu, says this means one should avoid attending Gentile theaters and circuses (a b'raisa also mentions amphitheaters/stadiums), which involved violent sporting (and idolatry). Presumably, this is not the exact application David had in mind in his time, but the analog in his generation would likely involve violent sporting, which led to the tragedies in the above comment.

Comment: Acting saved David's life when he pretended to be crazy. Seems odd he'd fully condemn it.

Comment: @DoubleAA And acting got Yaakov the berachos, and Leah a husband, etc. Obviously there's a vast difference between doing it l'toeles vs. otherwise.

Comment: What about the actress who came to David with a whole sob story, and then went *gotcha*?

Comment: Gosh, I don't know how to thank you both, @Fred and @ Sha.lom. I'm especially grateful for these amazing clarifications as well as for quoting me the exact sources ! May G.od bless you and your loved ones with lots of energy and countless joys !  Oh... And Hannouka Samea'h 

Comment: This goes for you too @Shalom (somehow StackExchange limited user mentions to one per comment...)